# Three.js - why won't vertices update?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a loop of circles that move independently. I'm trying to draw lines form the center of the canvas to their location. The lines work fine during setup, but their vertices aren't updating during render. Even though `testLine.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true`, when inspected this is, in fact, set to false.

```
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer, lines=[], items =[];

var numItems = 40;
var xspeed;
var yspeed;
var lineGeometry;
var testLineGeometry;

init();
animate();
function init() {
  container = document.createElement( 'div' );
  document.body.appendChild( container );
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf7f7f7);
  var geometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry( 20, 20 );
  lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var testLineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  for ( var i = 0; i < numItems; i ++ ) {
    var item = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0x000000 } ) );
    item.position.x = (Math.random() * 20.1 - 1);
    item.position.y = (Math.random() * 20.1 - 1);
    item.xspeed = Math.random() * 2.1 - 1;
    item.yspeed = Math.random() * 2.1 - 1;
    // item.position.normalize();
    items.push(item);
    scene.add( item );

    lineGeometry.vertices.push( item.position );

    testLineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(item.position.x, item.position.y, 0));
    testLineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    testLine = new THREE.Line( testLineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000} ) );
    lines.push(testLine);
    scene.add( testLine );

  }

  line = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000} ) );
  // scene.add( line );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  //
}

//
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
}
function render() {


items.forEach(circle => {
  circle.position.x += circle.xspeed;
  circle.position.y += circle.yspeed;

  if (circle.position.x > window.innerWidth / 2 || circle.position.x < -window.innerWidth / 2 ) {
    circle.xspeed *= -1;
  }

  if (circle.position.y > window.innerWidth / 2 || circle.position.y < -window.innerWidth / 2) {
    circle.yspeed *= -1;
  }
});

  testLine.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.z = 1000;

renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

How can I update the appropriate vertices of `testLine` during render?

Comment: Because `testLine.geometry.vertices` doesn't contain references to the positions of circles, it contains an array of new vectors.

Comment: @prisoner849 Am I not referring to the same thing with `testLineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(item.position.x, item.position.y, 0));` ?

Comment: The answer is "yes, you don't have references to positions of circles"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testLineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(item.position.x, item.position.y, 0));` I can't get why you do it like that. `z`-coordinate of your circles' positions is always 0, so you can simply assign those positions as items of your array for vertices of the `testLine`.

I reworked your code:

- pushed positions of circles straight into the array of vertices of `testLine` `testLineGeometry.vertices.push(item.position);`
- shared the same point for center;
- moved instantiating of`testLine` out of the `for`-loop;
- used `THREE.LineSegments()` instead of `THREE.Line()`, as your `testLine` contains two times more vertices than amount of circles;

```js
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer, lines = [],
  items = [];

var numItems = 40;
var xspeed;
var yspeed;
var lineGeometry;
var testLineGeometry;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf7f7f7);
  var geometry = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(20, 20);
  lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var testLineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var center = new THREE.Vector3();
  for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    var item = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: Math.random() * 0x000000
    }));
    item.position.x = (Math.random() * 20.1 - 1);
    item.position.y = (Math.random() * 20.1 - 1);
    item.xspeed = Math.random() * 2.1 - 1;
    item.yspeed = Math.random() * 2.1 - 1;
    // item.position.normalize();
    items.push(item);
    scene.add(item);

    lineGeometry.vertices.push(item.position);
    
    testLineGeometry.vertices.push(item.position);
    testLineGeometry.vertices.push(center);
  }

  testLine = new THREE.LineSegments(testLineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000
  }));
  lines.push(testLine);
  scene.add(testLine);

  line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000
  }));
  // scene.add( line );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  //
}

//
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {


  items.forEach((circle, idx) => {
    circle.position.x += circle.xspeed;
    circle.position.y += circle.yspeed;

    if (circle.position.x > window.innerWidth / 2 || circle.position.x < -window.innerWidth / 2) {
      circle.xspeed *= -1;
    }

    if (circle.position.y > window.innerWidth / 2 || circle.position.y < -window.innerWidth / 2) {
      circle.yspeed *= -1;
    }
  });

  testLine.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```